# Viewing downloaded .tif file from planet labs?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, planet

I am trying to download a specific area of interest using planet API. 
I've activated the image containing my area, which seems successful.
Then I'm downloading the tif file, which also gives a result, though not expected.   My implementation is in python.

Here is my activation.py file

```
import os
import requests

item_id = "20161015_204133_1_0c0b"
item_type = "PSScene3Band"
asset_type = "visual"

PL_API_KEY='your key'

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (PL_API_KEY, '')
# request an item
item = \
session.get(
("https://api.planet.com/data/v1/item-types/" +
"{}/items/{}/assets/").format(item_type, item_id))

# extract the activation url from the item for the desired asset
item_activation_url = item.json()[asset_type]["_links"]["activate"]

print("Activation URL: ",item_activation_url)

# request activation
response = session.post(item_activation_url)
print(response.status_code)
```

This is my response.

Activation URL:  (removed api url)
204

And my area of interest file, subarea.geojson

```
{
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                [
                  -121.92309379577637,
                  37.720983558420585
                ],
                [
                  -121.92190825939177,
                  37.71960024532617
                ],
                [
                  -121.92086756229399,
                  37.720139146443614
                ],
                [
                  -121.92214965820311,
                  37.72150547658797
                ],
                [
                  -121.92309379577637,
                  37.720983558420585
                ]
              ]

            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here is my download.py file

```
    from osgeo import gdal
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
    import os
    import requests

    item_id = "20161015_204133_1_0c0b"
    item_type = "PSScene3Band"
    asset_type = "visual"
    item_url = 'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/item-types/{}/items/{}/assets'.format(item_type, item_id)

    PLANET_API_KEY= 'xxxxxxxx'
    # Request a new download URL
    result = requests.get(item_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(PLANET_API_KEY, ''))
    download_url = result.json()[asset_type]['location']

    vsicurl_url = '/vsicurl/' + download_url
    output_file = item_id + '_subarea.tif'

    # GDAL Warp crops the image by our AOI, and saves it
    gdal.Warp(output_file, vsicurl_url, dstSRS = 'EPSG:4326', cutlineDSName 
    = 'subarea2.geojson', cropToCutline = True)
```

Note: I did make sure the area of interest is present inside the subarea(refer item_id).

Result file here.
[My result Image .tif file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nqtzu9MPQg891lOZZ-DD85sYW4uXDjvl)

Im opening the file using qgis,  I got nothing.

Comment: Running `gdalinfo -hist` for your image reveals that extent of the image is right but all the pixels have value 0 on all the bands. I believe that there is some problem in accessing the download_url or then there are no data in your area of interest.

Comment: What happens when you download `output_file` to disk then run `gdal.Warp` on it?

Comment: This is my output file. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xY_klqeYSMn2HWkBv97cKyrWvMuuBuWs before gdal.Warp

Comment: Your subarea seems to be outside the source image (too much west and south). Gdalinfo reports the lower left corner of the source as `121d48' 3.85"W, 37d47'29.60"N`. Your subarea is around 121.98 degrees W and 37.72 degrees N. Converting the minutes and seconds of gdalinfo report into decimal degrees will help with finding the error.

Comment: Thank you very much. An additional help needed if you could,

Comment: How can I omit the subarea.geojson file, and add coordinates directly to gdal.warp() function. I tried storing the feature into a variable and pass it to the function, It gives a syntax error. Any idea how to? It'll be very helpful.

Comment: `gdal.Translate(output_file, vsicurl_url, projWin=[ulx, uly, lrx, lry])`. See http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions

Comment: I  tried this. Didn't work out . gdal.Translate(output_file, vsicurl_url, projWin=[
             [ -121.58629417419435,
              37.869026597400435
            ], [
              -121.56612396240234,
              37.869026597400435
            ], [
              -121.56612396240234,
              37.879121568009225
            ], [
              -121.56612396240234,
              37.869026597400435
            ],[
              -121.58629417419435,
              37.879121568009225
            ]])

Comment: ProjWin is all wrong, give as documented upper left x and y followed by lower right x and y.

Comment: Alright, but there are instances where I may need to warp a polygon which has more than 4 points. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Use correct cutline. What you originally did with GeoJSON was OK but the polygon was outside your image.